# Filter SQL Query based on Non-Alpha First Character

Tags: sql, filter, filtering

I'm trying to filter a VARCHAR column where the first letter is NOT an alpha.

Ex.
values = ['.net', '30 days', 'apple', 'beta']

returns ['.net', '30 days']

Note: for reference this is to group the names into filter buckets by first letter, where anything not an alpha character is grouped into '#' (think iPhone Contacts Browse grouping).

Filtering on a single alpha is easy with LIKE or substring, but I can't find a simple way to filter for ALL non-alpha characters.

EDIT: It is case-sensitive, but I'm expecting all lower-case, all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the solution as easy as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE SomeColumn NOT LIKE '[A-z]%'
```

?

**EDIT:** Changed [A-Z] to [A-z] just in case you're using a case-sensitive collation.

Comment: +1 Nice one. Works on sql server. But is it compatible across all databases?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the LIKE operator is supported by more than just T-SQL. I don't have enough experience with other systems to give you a definitive list, but I suggest trying it and reporting back.

Comment: `LIKE` is portable. The range syntax isn't AFAIK. BTW it is best to use `'[A-z]%'` so it works correctly on case sensitive collations for strings like `zebra`

Comment: Are we allowed to answer our own questions? A colleague suggested an alternate query for this case:  
`SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn < 'a'`

Comment: @miguardo Bad idea IMHO. Check the table of ASCII codes and you'll see that some non-alphas are after 'z', and there are more non-alphas between 'Z' and 'a'.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table
where ASCII(Name) NOT BETWEEN 65/* A */ and 90/* Z */
 AND ASCII(Name) NOT BETWEEN 97 /* a */ AND 122 /* z */
```

You didn't specify flavor so this is TSQL though I believe ASCII is supported in most SQL implementations. The inline comment characters (/* */) may differ.

Comment: Won't use an index at all. LIKE is in the [SQL standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) and *may* use an index at least. ASCII *isn't* mentioned in ANSI SQL 92